# Word Identification

Tags: word, wordplay

Sound out the word with the clues. My first one, should be quite easy:

1. You can regularly find me inserted below.
2. Something we all do.
3. A short-hand account of the matter from my point of view.
4. I heard I finished 5th, but I was actually in 25th place.

Hints:

> 1. You can also find me near the end.
>  2. We share this commonality with trees.
>  3. "His", "her", "their" etcetera will work in place of "my".
>  4. Has already been worked out.

Comment: 25th place lets met think of "y" straight away...

Comment: @the4seasons That, combined with "My first one, should be quite _easy_" ...

Comment: Is the final answer "wordplay"?

Comment: @mmking Is that asking for the actual answer, or whether it's got an incorrect tag?

Comment: No, I just had an idea and don't have the time to type up everything at the moment.

Comment: @mmking Sorry, incorrect :)

Comment: @mmking Wordplay is what I thought too.  **Word** is the tag for this post, we all **p**ee.  Not sure about LA, but the 25th letter is **y**

Comment: Is the third a side? Like hearing someones side of the story?

Comment: @Bard incorrect sorry

Comment: @Bard but you're on the right lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> DELIVERY

You can regularly find me inserted below.

> From Sabre in the comments: It's DEL, as in the key below INS(ert) and near END on a keyboard

Something we all do.

> LIVE as confirmed in Sabre's answer.

A short-hand account of the matter from my point of view.

> I'm going with "version", the "short-hand" of which is VER.

I heard I finished 5th, but I was actually in 25th place.

> Solved awhile ago as Y

Combined:

> DEL + LIVE + VER + Y = DELIVERY

Comment: +1 I was just about to post this. Almost certain it's right

Comment: **Correct!**, although number 1 is still miles from the answer.

Comment: It's **DEL**, as in the key *below INS(ert)* and *near END* on a keyboard

Comment: @Sabre **DING** :) - I was just about to say I'll mark this as correct when that's been worked out because that answer is **KEY** :P

Comment: Yeesh, at this point it looks like I only actually solved 1/4 of the answer!

Comment: @VictorHenry I would mark Sabre's as accepted because he answered two of them, however his answer is incorrect so I'll just award him with some rep using nefarious means ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a stretch, but it's worth a shot...

1. You can regularly find me inserted below.

   > *(You can also find me near the end.)*
   >  "You respond to posts, giving us **RE**" (from [qwertylpc's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18398/4513))
2. Something we all do.

   > *(We share this commonality with trees.)*
   >  All animals and plants **LIVE**
3. A short-hand account of the matter from my point of view.

   > *("His", "her", "their" etcetera will work in place of "my".)*
   >  On SE, I give my point of view in an answer. Short-hand for that is **ANS**
4. I heard I finished 5th, but I was actually in 25th place.

   > *(Has already been worked out.)*
   >  The 25th letter is **Y**, but it sounds like the 5th letter, e.

Sound out the word with the clues.

> RE-LIVE-ANS-Y = **RELEVANCY**

Comment: Nice one. 1) Still quite far off I'm afraid. 2) **DING!** 3) You've understood the short-hand part, still incorrect though.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> COMMENT

Let's see at these lines:
You can regularly find me inserted below.

> Comments are usually posted below question/topic post.

Something we all do.

> We all make comments (so: we all comment things)

A short-hand account of the matter from my point of view.

> Comments wouldn't contribute to any change, normally. These are just comments.

I finally finish in 25th place.

> (no idea yet)

I'm aware I may misunderstood 3rd verse. If so, please tell me so.

Comment: Nice, 1, 2 and 3 fit, although it's sounding out the word. So for example if the answer was "Abercrombe" then the the answers to the questions would be "Ah", "Ber", "Crom", and "Bee". I've realised number 4 might be confusing in that aspect so I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word is

> **VISIONARY**

1. You can regularly find me inserted below.

   > **V** comes under (or after) U in the English alphabet.
2. Something we all do.

   > We all **see** with our eyes.
3. A short-hand account of the matter from my point of view.

   > On television/radio, short versions of news are broadcast or rather, the news goes **on air**. (*This is probably a stretch, but it fits the overall aim...*)
4. I heard I finished 5th, but I was actually in 25th place.

   > **Y** is the 25th alphabet, but in some words (like the one I claim) it gives the sound of E, which is the 5th alphabet.

Putting it all together

> **V See Onair Y** which looks and sounds a lot like the word **VISIONARY**.

Comment: 1) Quite far off I'm afraid. 2) Fits, but not the answer. 3) Along the right lines, very close, but it's more broadly speaking that that. 4) bang on. Also I pronounce that word "visj-ah-nair-ree" with a silent J (I don't know how to annotate that sound :/), but that might just be my English accent :).

Comment: @JamieBarker: it's commonly referred to as the "zh" sound (the voiced counterpart to "sh") - English doesn't have a commonly known name for it though

Answer (score 1):

How about

1

> Tag - inserted below the questions

2

> Lie - we all do it, though some more than others

3

> Tale - my version of the story

4

> Y - 25th Letter

Giving:

> Tagliatelle

Comment: Nice try! It fits, although number 1 is much more specific than that. Number 2 is not a concious decision. 3 is incorrect too, although fits like a glove :)

Answer (score -1):

The word is

> **EASY**

**Explanation**

You can regularly find me inserted below.

> Normally in tasks lists, easy tasks will be placed/inserted below.

Something we all do.

> All of us can do things that are easy.

A short-hand account of the matter from my point of view.

> Seeing/facing simple tasks/things, people think 'easy (ez)'

I finally finish in 25th place.

> Easy finishes with 'Y', the last letter, which is the 25th alphabet.

Comment: Incorrect I'm afraid. Personally I put easy tasks to the top of lists ;)