# Word Identification (2)

Tags: word, wordplay

A follow on from my [first one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/word-identification).

Sound out the word with the clues:

1. I can move to the right, but also shift to the left.
2. Actually, I'm not quite sure now.
3. Oh wait, now I've got the hang of it.
4. But now I'm slaughtered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I can move to the right, but also shift to the left.

> That's got to be TAB, as in the tab key on a computer keyboard. Tab moves you to the right, but shift+tab moves you to the left.

2. Actually, I'm not quite sure now.

> I'm guessing this is something like ER - a noise made when not quite sure.

3. Oh wait, now I've got the hang of it.

> You've got the KNACK of it (thanks @Mnemonic).

4. But now I'm slaughtered.

> You've been CULLed.

Overall answer:

> TAB+ER+KNACK+CULL - "Sound out the word" = TABERNACLE.

Comment: I think you're right about ROT13(gnoreanpyr), and the two you're missing are ROT13(xanpx naq xvyy).

Comment: Close! 4 still isn't correct and doesn't sound the word out correctly.

Comment: @JamieBarker OK, I think I got it this time.